# How to write conditions for paginate finder to retrieve items based on associated item in a many to many relation?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP 3.x

I am following the bookmarkr tutorial found [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html) and [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/part-two.html)

I want to add one more feature where I can fetch bookmarks that belong to the same tag based on tag id.

I wrote the following function in BookmarksController

```
/**
 * Index view by tag method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function index_by_tag($tag_id) {
        $conditions = [
            'Bookmarks.public' => true,
        ];
        $this->paginate = [
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'contain' => [
                'Users' => function ($q) {
                   return $q
                        ->select(['username', 'id']);
                }
            ],
            'order' => [
                'Bookmarks.updated' => 'desc', 
                'Bookmarks.id' => 'desc'
            ]
        ];
        $this->set('bookmarks', $this->paginate($this->Bookmarks));
    }
```

How should I alter the `$conditions` so I can retrieve only those bookmarks that belong to same tag?

Bear in mind that Bookmarks and Tags are in a many to many relation.

**UPDATE1**

I found this idea of using `matching`. Which gets me what I want if I use `query builder`.

See http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-matching-when-finding-results

However, there is no mention of how to use `matching` with paginate.

**UPDATE2**

I just realized there is already a custom finder method that does what I want except that it does not work with the paginate.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html#getting-bookmarks-with-a-specific-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in changing the `tags` action in BookmarksController.php

Originally in the tutorial, the tags action look like this:

```
public function tags() {
    $tags = $this->request->params['pass'];

    $bookmarks = $this->Bookmarks->find('tagged', [
        'tags' => $tags
    ]);

    $this->set(compact('bookmarks', 'tags'));
}
```

The change lies in changing how to define `$bookmarks`.

```
public function tags() {
    $tags = $this->request->params['pass'];

    // you can call custom finder methods within paginate
    // the link is at http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#using-controller-paginate
    // scroll down just a bit to look at custom finder methods
    $this->paginate = [
        'finder' => [
            'tagged' => [
                'tags' => $tags
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $bookmarks = $this->paginate($this->Bookmarks);

    $this->set(compact('bookmarks', 'tags'));
}
```